# When error frame generate, How does relate to Trasmit Error Count?

Tags: can-bus, canoe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p2MU.png)I have a question. I am using CANoe Simulation tool.

I know when a Error frame occurs. I heard that Error Frame condition is Transmit Error Count Should be

greater than 127.But first of all, On Screen Capture, An error frame occurs even though it is less than

127. What is the reason? and, Transmit Error Count 7 means consecutive dominant value error?

I want to clarify that ECU can't receive HU_DATC_E_03 Message because of Error Frame.

Please Help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRPfu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it backwards: functioning CAN nodes are always allowed to send error frames. Until the counter reaches 127, the node is in "error active" mode. Which means that the node is allowed to actively send error frames.

Beyond 127 it goes "error passive". This means that it is no longer allowed to send error frames, because the node is considered broken and should not be allowed to disrupt bus traffic any longer. It may still listen to the bus but not actively participate.

I don't know this specific tool, but tx error count supposedly just means that the tx error counter has reached the value 7 - that is, there have been 7 failed attempts to send a frame, for whatever reason. It shouldn't have anything necessarily have anything to do with bit stuffing (and CAN bit stuffs after 5 data bits, not 6 as some other networks do).